# Log all terminal commands in file

Tags: linux, syslog

I've tried this solution: https://askubuntu.com/a/858319 
It works good but the only trouble with syslog is that commands from SCREEN can't be logged.
If someone tried anything else, or knows better way to log all inputted commands in Linux terminal?

Answer (score 1):

Use `script`. It saves everything including the output.

Comment: Using script is also not the best way. I have added script command in each user's .bashrc and each time when user log in, terminal become frozen for a split second. Another trouble is that the users should not know the logger working, should not see their log_files and should now have a rights to edit/remove/delete log file of their own inputs.